# colocar Thread.sleep no metodo Call do Retrofit sem travar a UI Thread (principal)

Tags: java, android

Bom pelo que eu entendi o método `call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {` inicia uma *thread* para se comunicar com *webservice*. Então pensei em retardar o método colocando um `thread.sleep(2000)` para exibir meu `ProgressDialog` percebi que colocando o `sleep` não interrompia a *thead* criada pelo *retrofit* e sim a principal *Ui thread*  travando o `ProgressDialog`.

Tem algum jeito para colocar um `Thread.sleep` dentro do método `call.enqueue` para simular uma demora de resposta do *webserver*?

```
package com.amazongas.paulo.crudbasicandroid.dao;

import android.util.Log;

import com.amazongas.paulo.crudbasicandroid.api.ApiCallback;
import com.amazongas.paulo.crudbasicandroid.api.DataService;
import com.amazongas.paulo.crudbasicandroid.model.Contato;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ContatoDao {

    public void salvar(Contato contato, final ApiCallback callback){

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = gson.toJson(contato);

        DataService dataService = DataService.retrofit.create(DataService.class);

        Call<Contato> call = dataService.gravar(contato.getNome(),contato.getTelefone());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Contato>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Contato> call, Response<Contato> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){

                    //Simular retardo do server

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    callback.onResponse(response.body() != null);

                    //Boolean success = response.body().getSuccess();
                    int lastId = response.body().getCod();
                    Log.d("resultado","JSON: "+lastId);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Contato> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                callback.onResponse(false);
                Log.d("resultado","JSON: ERROR");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: De acordo com https://square.github.io/retrofit/, `On Android, callbacks will be executed on the main thread`, ou seja, não há como simular um tempo de espera pelo callback do Retrofit sem travar a UI. Você pode mockar o webserver e fazer a request demorar 2segs... Parece que eles tem uma API de mock https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object,%20long)):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(() -> salvar(contato, callback), 2000);
```